# Change Textview Text in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating my first app in android, I use drawer layout with a Service which get current location and send data to a Broadacast receiver, this one should be update latitude and longitude textview in Dashboard Fragment, but when updateDashLocation is called I receive this error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference for DashLatitude.setText(latitude); and DashLongitude.setText(longitude);

Fragment code

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {


public DashboardFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

View dashboardInflatedView;
TextView DashLatitude,DashLongitude;
String TAG = "GPSTracker";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Toolbar toolbar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).toolbar;
    toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");

    dashboardInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    DashLatitude = (TextView)dashboardInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.DashLatitude);
    DashLongitude = (TextView)dashboardInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.DashLongitude);

    return dashboardInflatedView;
}

public void updateDashLocation(String latitude, String longitude){

    //Log.d(TAG, "Update Dashboard Location");
    DashLatitude.setText(latitude);
    DashLongitude.setText(longitude);
}
```

}

How can I access to elements of Dashboard fragment when updateDashLocation is called?

Comment: Looks like the updateDashLocation is being called before the fragment view is created

Comment: Are you sure you have the right id's for your views?

Comment: id's are correct! updateDashLocation is called after fragment creation. After delete cash I repeat test, I receive Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference, if I put DashLatitude.setText("test"); during onCreateView of fragment, text are update correctly... In some way I cannot access to fragment View in the same fragment after inflater! Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your TextViews when the updateDashLocation method is called?

```
    public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

        public DashboardFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        View dashboardInflatedView;
        TextView DashLatitude,DashLongitude;
        String TAG = "GPSTracker";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Toolbar toolbar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).toolbar;
            toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");

            dashboardInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
            return dashboardInflatedView;
        }

        public void updateDashLocation(String latitude, String longitude){

            DashLatitude = (TextView)dashboardInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.DashLatitude);
            DashLongitude = (TextView)dashboardInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.DashLongitude);

            //Log.d(TAG, "Update Dashboard Location");
            DashLatitude.setText(latitude);
            DashLongitude.setText(longitude);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was in main activity, now in the broadcast receiver, when coordinates as been passed, the code is:

```
// Define the callback for what to do when data is received
private BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Broadcastreceiver Coordinates");

        int resultCode = intent.getIntExtra("resultCode", RESULT_CANCELED);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Double latitude= intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0);
            Double longitude= intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude",0);

            DashboardFragment dashboardFrag  = (DashboardFragment)
                    manager.findFragmentByTag("Dashboard");
            dashboardFrag .updateLocation(latitude.toString(),longitude.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, latitude.toString()+" --- "+longitude.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

I get fragment by Tag and access to methods